# How to use Textview output for another class method?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have just started using eclipse adt(android developer tool) and i am working on electricbill calculator app. The app interface looks like this: [App interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKocj.png)

The user will input a value in previous consumption and current consumption then calculate(1st button) to get the total consumption. Then enter the rate  and compute(2nd button, multiplies total consumption and rate) to get the electricbill.

My main activity contains onClickListeners for the buttons. The first part of the calculation works, but when i try to input a value and rate and compute it, the application crashes and i dont know where is the problem. Here is my code:

Calculate Button

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText PrevConEdt, CurrConEdt, RateEdt;
    TextView ConsumptionTv, ElectricBillTv;
    Button CalculateBtn, ComputeBtn, ClearBtn, ClearBtn2;
    Double rateDbl, cbillDbl, consumptionDbl, prevDbl, currentDbl;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        PrevConEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPreviousConsumption);
        CurrConEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentConsumption);
        RateEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEnterRate);
        
        ConsumptionTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConsumption);
        ElectricBillTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEbill);
        
        CalculateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        CalculateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View Calculate) {
                
                String prev, current, consumption;
                 prev = PrevConEdt.getText().toString();
                 current = CurrConEdt.getText().toString();
                 
                 if(PrevConEdt.length() == 0){
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Consumption Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     return;
                 }else if(CurrConEdt.length() == 0){
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Consumption Required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     return;
                     
                 }else{
                     Double prevDbl, currentDbl, consumptionDbl;
                     prevDbl = Double.parseDouble(prev);
                     currentDbl = Double.parseDouble(current);

                     
                     if(currentDbl < prevDbl){
                         //String msg = "Current should be greater than previous.";
                         //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                         //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, duration).show();
                         //PrevConEdt.requestFocus();
                         CurrConEdt.setError("Current should be greater than previous.");
                         return;
                         
                         
                     }else{
                         consumptionDbl = currentDbl - prevDbl;
                         String consumptionStr = String.format("%.2f kWh", consumptionDbl);
                         ConsumptionTv.setText(consumptionStr);
                     }
                     
                     
                     
                     
                     
                 }
                 
                 
            } 
            
            
            
            
            
            
        });
```

Compute Button

```
ComputeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCompute);
        ComputeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View compute) {
                
                
                String rate, consumption;
                rate = RateEdt.getText().toString();
                consumption = ConsumptionTv.getText().toString();
                
                if(RateEdt.length() == 0){
                    RateEdt.setError("Rate is required.");
                    return;
                }else{
                    Double rateDbl, cbillDbl, consumptionDbl;
                    rateDbl = Double.parseDouble(rate);
                    consumptionDbl = Double.parseDouble(consumption);
                    
                    
                    cbillDbl = consumptionDbl *  rateDbl;
                    String billStr = String.format("Php %.2f", cbillDbl);
                    ElectricBillTv.setText(billStr);
                    
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Share your crash log.

Comment: Hi, Im not sure if this ist 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 10001 2023-01-09 22:58:20.767
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Unknown javadoc format for TextView [in TextView.class [in android.widget [in C:\Users\TOSHIBA SAT-C655 PC\Downloads\MOBILE APP\EclipseADT\sdk\platforms\android-17\android.jar]]]]
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 1009 2023-01-09 22:58:20.767
!MESSAGE Unknown javadoc format for TextView [in TextView.class [in android.widget [in C:\Users\TOSHIBA SAT-C655 PC\Downloads\MOBILE APP\EclipseADT\sdk\platforms\android-17\android.jar]]]